# Помогите доработать js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите доработать данный код

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="country">
    <option value="1">Андрей</option>
    <option value="2">Виталий</option>
    <option value="3">Максим</option>
    <option value="4">Денис</option>
    <option value="5">Виктор</option>
    </select>
  <div></div>
<script>
    $("#country").change(function () {
          var str = "";
        str = $("#country option:selected").val();
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .change();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Смотрите я хочу <script> перенести в head но тогда вывод работать не будет, хотелось бы сделать что бы можно было <script> перенесет в head и допустим вставить в дизайн данную строку

```
<div id="country"></div>
```

И что бы на этом месте показывался текст который я выбрал, и вот как добавить данный код в select

```
array('1'=>'Андрей','2'=>'Виталий','3'=>'Максим','4'=>'Денис','5'=>'Виктор');
```

Comment: @vanchester ниже все правильно написал. JS работает с тем контентом, который присутствует в момент его выполнения на странице, поэтому надо либо пихать его в конец страницы (не очень элегантное решение), либо откладывать его выполнение (то, что написал @vanchester и является де-факто стандартом). Вы еще наверняка с этим столкнетесь, когда будете динамически создавать элементы.

Answer (score 3):

оберните код в

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* ваш JS код */ });
```

Так он будет выполняться после загрузки страницы, и вы сможете вставлять его в любое место страницы